# A problem on the optimal estimate $|f''(\xi)|\geq \frac{4}{(b-a)^2}|f(b)-f(a)|$.

Tags: taylor-expansion

Let $f$ be twice differentiable on $[a,b]$. $f'(\frac{a+b}{2})=0$. Then it is easy to deduce $|f''(\xi)|\geq \frac{4}{(b-a)^2}|f(b)-f(a)|$ for some $\xi\in (a,b)$ by the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $\frac{a+b}{2}$, with points $a,b$; that is, $f(b)=f(\frac{a+b}{2})+f'(\frac{a+b}{2})(b-\frac{a+b}{2})+\frac{f''(\eta)}{2}(b-\frac{a+b}{2})^2$; $f(a)=f(\frac{a+b}{2})+f'(\frac{a+b}{2})(a-\frac{a+b}{2})+\frac{f''(\zeta)}{2}(a-\frac{a+b}{2})^2$. We substract to get the desired result by letting $\xi=\eta$ or $\zeta$ depending on the amplitide of $|f''(\eta)|,|f''(\zeta)|$.

Now my question is as follows:

(1) the constant $4$ is optimal in the sense that for any $M>4$, we can find $a,b$ and a function $f$ satisfying the assumptions that for all $x\in [a,b]$, $|f''(x)|< \frac{4}{(b-a)^2}|f(b)-f(a)|$.

(2) If $f$ is not constant, then $\exists\ \eta\in (a,b)$, such that $|f''(\eta)|>\frac{4}{(b-a)^2}|f(b)-f(a)|.$

On these two problems, I have no idea.

On (1), a possible idea is to consider $f(x)$ as a modifincaiton of $x$ over $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$.

Answer (score 2):

(1) You want $M$, not $4$, in the last formula of this part.  Try an $f$ for which $f''$ is constant.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/817976)

Comment: @Oussama Boussif: I would say that this does in fact provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @carmichael561 I flagged it because it is too short for answer and fits as a comment.